# seen you more than my last two husbands

Tags: meaning, plural-forms

a. I have seen you more than my last two husbands.

Does that mean

1. I have seen you more than my last two husbands combined.

or

2. I have seen you more than either of my last two husbands.

Comment: Seems like intent is humorous exaggeration, so I'd go with *combined*.

Answer (score 1):

It is not meant to be taken literally, it really only means I've seen you a lot.

If you are to take it literally it is semantically ambiguous, since it could mean "the total amount I have ever seen you exceeds the total amount I saw my last two husbands" or "the amount I've seen you each week exceeds the amount I saw either of my last two husbands per week", or conceivably "the total amount I've seen you exceeds the total amount I saw either of my last two husbands."

It is also syntactically ambiguous, it could mean "I've seen you more than either my two husband have seen you".

But since it is not a scientific reporting of a matter of fact, but a joking comment nobody cares about any particular ambiguity.